# Twitter Bootstrap: Hidden Panel and Equal Alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I still don't quite understand the responsive grid in Bootstrap so I am asking for help.

I have a row within which I would like the following:
[1] on desktops and above: 3 panels of content with the central panel centered on the page
[2] on laptops and below: 2 panels of content with the "central panel" hidden

Here is the frame I am currently using but on large monitors, the central panel is not centered (as if the first panel is 6 cols)

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">LEFT</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md" style="text-align: center;">CENTRAL</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">RIGHT</div>
```

I know something is wrong but I can't figure out another way to code this to get what I need.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid has 12 columns in total so to have 3 panels for desktops change the `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-4` for all three panels so left + central + right = 12 cols. Similarly since you need only two panels for `md` then do `col-md-6` for left and right and hiding the central panel as you are doing should to the trick.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">LEFT</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md" style="text-align: center;">CENTRAL</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">RIGHT</div>
```

Also optional but if you don't want to have the inline style for the central panel you could add the class `text-center` that comes prepacked with bootstrap.

Another thing to remember is that bootstrap is "mobile first" which means that if you use the smallest sizing class available say `col-xs-*`, it will be used for all windows sizes unless overridden by `col-sm/md/lg-*`. So col-xs-6 will work for all windows sizes except for desktops if you use both classes `"col-xs-6 col-lg-4"`. So for laptops and below:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">LEFT</div>
<!-- Will work -->
<!-- <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md text-center">CENTRAL</div> -->

<!-- Simpler to use visible-lg-* see link below -->
<div class="col-lg-4 visible-lg-block text-center">CENTRAL</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">RIGHT</div>
```

responsive utilities i.e. visible-*-*, hidden-* work a little different please see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: That makes so much more sense than mine ... thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @jgravois You bet! I just realized that you said laptops and below so I've expanded my answer to cover those "tiny" cases.. no pun intended =]